# Awstats + Postfix logs - no senders/recipients?

Tags: smtp, log-files, awstats

I am trying to configure awstats (v7.6 from repo on Ubuntu 18.04) to process postfix log files. But I don't have much log data to work with.
Awstats is reporting that it has processed the data and the summary shows the expected number of messages and cumulative size, however the details (and I specifically need a list of senders) is blank.

The relevant parts of the config:

```
LogFile="/usr/local/bin/maillogconvert.pl standard </var/log/mail.log.1 |"
LogType=M
LogFormat="%time2 %email %email_r %host %host_r %method %url %code %bytesd"
ValidSMTPCodes="1 250"
ShowEMailSenders=HBML
ShowEMailReceivers=HBML
ShowSMTPErrorsStats=1
MaxNbOfDomain = 10
MinHitDomain  = 1
MaxNbOfEMailsShown = 200
MinHitEMail   = 1
```

On both the summary and details pages, Awstats shows a count of 0 for senders and recipients / no accounts listed.

This appears to be a display issue since the data file contains the expected details:

```
BEGIN_EMAILSENDER 1
user@example.com 20 29105 20200430151927
END_EMAILSENDER
```

HTML is being generated dynamically, not saved reports. Data in extract above has been anonimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that awstats was working - but was being accessed via a proxy which was caching incorrectly.